# set horizontal data in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have excel 2007 and using Windows 10. I made a scatter diagram using columns A and B. It created the diagram. Excel used column A for the Y axis and labeled as such. And it used column B for the X axis ... but it didn't label the X axis as expected (it labeled it with row numbers but the data is dates).

I have searched for instructions on how to select the data for the X axis but non of the references I found worked.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

I have attached a picture here. Notice the x axis has sequential numbers. I want it to have the dates from column B. I would also prefer it to scale according to the dates.

[image]

Comment: Click on one of the data markers in the graph.  The ranges used for the x and y values should then have colored outlines around them (if your graph is on the same sheet as the data).  You can then drag or resize the outlines to specify the correct ranges,

Comment: That caused the x values to be displayed on the line. The x axis is still just sequential numbers. I want the x axis labels to be dates. Maybe I didn't describe it correctly. I will provide a picture in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how to fix the x-axis values on your graph.

You need to follow these instructions **EXACTLY**.  If you don’t get the expected result, you need to **Post Pictures** of your result.  To do this, **EDIT YOUR QUESTION** and add a picture by clicking on the Image icon in the header (to the right of the curly brackets).  You figured out how to do this once before - it’s not that hard.  You can only put pictures in your question, not in comments.

OK, here we go.

1. Right-click on the edge of your graph to select it and hit the DELETE key.  If your graph doesn’t disappear, see [this help page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-do-i-delete-an-entire-chart-in-excel-2007/f5858b10-530d-4c1f-92da-f702b15140ed).
2. Move your data columns around so the Dates are in column A and the Numbers are in column B.  If you don’t know how to do this, see [this help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-or-copy-rows-and-columns-3ebbcafd-8566-42d8-8023-a2ec62746cfc).
3. Select the Dates and Numbers by clicking in the upper left cell (the first date) and dragging to the lower right cell (the last number).  When you’ve done that, you should see something like this:

[image]

4. Now open the Insert tab on the Excel ribbon. Click on Scatter in the Charts section to expand the chart options box. Select the third item down on the left, Straight Lined Scatter, from this box.  **Make sure you select from the "Scatter" icon and NOT the "Line" icon**.  The dialog box in Excel 2007 looks like this:

[image]

Now you will see your data plotted correctly on a Lined Scatter Graph:

[image]

And clicking on the line of the graph will show the correct x- and y-data ranges.

If your graph doesn't look like this, then Read Steps 1 through 4 Again, **especially the bold part of Step 4**, and [see this help page](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/17778.aspx).

Comment: I have followed lots of instructions on the internet but every one leaves out a step. FINALLY, instructions that are precise.